# How to use except block with pylance errors in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-except

I wanted to create a code block except with a pylance error : reportMissingImports. But python doesn't recognize this error because it comes from pylance. Can anyone please tell me how to use except code block with pylance error ? Or give me the equivalent of this error in python basic errors ?

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to work out what you're asking. Can you clarify, perhaps with a code sample if appropriate?

Comment: Pylance is an external program reading your code, so a try / except will not help: you code  is being _read_, not _executed_.  You might be able to disable `reportMissingImports` in PyLance's configuration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```py
try:
    import module
except ImportError:
    # import other_module 
    # pass
```

I think that is roughly the closest Exception that might be triggered at runtime.

You would want to uncomment one of the two lines in the `except` block depending on your use case.